# Get data from SQL table to empty variable

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to search in table(called Accounts) for Username and in the line of this user in coulmn 4 that called PhotoId there is string that i need to get and add it to empty string value that i made before. thats what i tryied
i want to do it by Query like my code

```
string ecid = e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id.ToString();
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Accounts where Username like @username", con))
{
    con.Open();
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", ecid);
    string variable;
    string userfound = (string)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    if (userfound == ecid)
    {
        using (SqlCommand GotPhoto = new SqlCommand("SELECT PhotoId from Accounts where Username like @user", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            GotPhoto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", ecid);

            DataPid = GotPhoto.ExecuteScalarAsync().ToString();
            con.Close();

            //  await bot.SendPhotoAsync("xxx", DataPid, capo, parseMode: ParseMode.Markdown, replyMarkup: zz);

            await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(cid, "its been Poster", parseMode: ParseMode.Html);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not Working");
    }
}
```

Comment: You stated a goal, and you showed some goal that appears to try to accomplish that goal. But you haven't actually stated your problem. I presume something is wrong with your code. What's wrong? Do you get an exception? What line? What's the exception? If you don't get an exception, then how does this code not perform as desired?

Comment: @mason i dont get any exception but when i click in my bot on the inline button thats execute that query im getting the not working msgbox , the user that i clicked with on the inline bot is registered in the table so why do i get not working msg box??

ecid = username
so if the user exsit its suppost to get the PhotoId string from there and put the string in DataPid

Comment: You perform a `SELECT *` it returns the first column when using ExecuteScalar , are you sure its the ID of the user ?

Comment: @Kobi what i want to do is that to search for username string that equals ecid if ecid is found i want to get the PhotoId cell string in this line to empty vrirable

Comment: Have you checked what is the value in userfound? e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id.ToString() does this object gives you usenane or some id? As your object naming are confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are combining a `SELECT * ...` with `ExecuteScalar()`, which "returns the value of the first column in the first row of the resultset. Additional rows and columns are ignored."(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx). Probably username is not the first column in the accounts table, so the content of another column is retured and your comparison fails.

Use `SELECT username from Accounts where Username like @username` instead.

**EDIT**

Depending on your data-model you can also combine the two queries into one as you are querying the same row twice.

```
con.Open();
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PhotoId from Accounts where Username like @user", con)) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", ecid);
    using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
        if (!reader.HasRows || ! reader.Read()) {
            MessageBox.Show("User not found");
        } else {
            DataPid = cmd.GetYOURDATATYPE(0).ToString();
            //....
        }

    }
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: im trying to do the same thing but to delete this 2 row from the line where @user , how can i do it in one Query please ?

Comment: @MatanMalka I'm not sure, I understand what you want to acomplish

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) =>

*Executes the query, and returns the **first column** of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.*

When you perform `string userfound = (string)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();`

You are comparing the username to a value ( but wich one ? the value of the first column in the create table instruction)

I Suggest you change the first query to be sure to `select username`

PS:

- To be consistant, you can also rename both of your query parameter `@username` instead of `@user` and `@username` because it refers exactly to the same thing.
- You can perform only one query instead of two. (  select photoid ... where username = .. , and just check if the result contains one row )

Comment: Thank you very much , that's helped me and teaching me something that i struggle with